# Speech Segmentation SDK for Unity3d?

Tags: sdk, unity-game-engine, speech

I would like to know if it is possible to segment the voice audio into multiple audio files with the single word per file using any Software that could be integrated with Unity3d game engine.

Say for example, " Hello world!, welcome to Unity!", I would like to get it segmented as Hello.mp3, world.mp3,welcome.mp3, to.mp3, Unity.mp3 ( it may be any sort of audio format playable in Mac).

Comment: Unity is a game engine, not good at an audio processing. You might try to segment it outside unity and import it back when it is already segmented.

Comment: In that case what could be helpful at the best to do this process? @David

Comment: I would suggest you using professional audio file editors, e.g. Ableton. not sure, :)

Comment: You can use [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net). There are few developers which integrated CMUSphinx into Unity as a plugin.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev as far as from my research , I found no concrete statement or procedure for integrating CMUSphinx with Unity game engine,

Comment: As @NikolayShmyrev suggests, I've done some tests integrating CMUSphinx with Unity. I was using sockets to have Unity talk to an external Java service doing the heavy lifting. You will have to decide where to do the audio capture. On my OSX setup. I had Sphinx take care of it and would run perfectly in the background with the Unity project running full screen.